# How can I combine two arrays of vector components into an array of vectors in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, cell-array

I have two arrays of the same size, `ux` and `uy`, which I want to combine into a cell array of vectors such that `U(1,1)` contains a vector composed of `uy(1,1),ux(1,1)` and `numel(U)=numel(ux)=numel(uy)'

The components `ux` and `uy` represent the unit vector of the image gradient. The component arrays are created by elementwise multiplication:

```
ux = I1x./I1mag;
uy = I1y./I1mag;
```

I need to be able to access each vector multiple times, and call them as arguments of `dot` and `cross` and making an array of vectors would be faster and more convenient than creating an ad hoc vector for each one on every iteration where it is called.

Thanks

Edit for further clarity:

suppose I have an array

```
uy = (1,2,3;4,5,6);
```

and another array of the same size

```
ux = (9,8,7;6,5,4);
```

I need the yx vectors, so for our example that's

([1,9], [2,8], [3,7]; [4,6], [5,5], [6,4])

What's the most efficient way to do that, please? I'm going to get dot products of each pixel with its neighbours and vice versa, so each vector will be used 16 times and the full arrays contain on the order of 10^4 or 10^5 elements...

Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: Do you want the cell array to be `numel(uy) x numel(ux)`?

Comment: Assuming `ux` has one column, `[ux, uy]`. Otherwise, `[ux', uy']`. Or, `[ux; uy]'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll edit the post to clarify - I want numel(U) = numel(ux) = numel (uy), but each so cell of U contains a vector [uy, ux].

Comment: Why do you want a cell array? If all of the elements are the same size, a multidimensional array would be simpler to deal with.

Comment: I need to be able to call the vector for dot and cross products... being able to get something like dot(U(x,y), U(a,b)) would be handy. Otherwise I could call it as U1 = [U(x,y,1), U(x,y,2)] and then dot(U1, U2), but won't this be slower?

Comment: What you want to do sounds simple enough, but we have no idea what your matrices look like. Some sample input and desired output would help tremendously.

Comment: If you're looking to compute the dot product on the two matrices, use `arrayfun(@dot,ux,uy)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **create two layers**. One layer contains **ux** and other layer contains **uy**.

```
ux = [10 8 7;6 5 4];
uy = [1 2 3;4 5 6];

xy(:,:,1) = ux; // [10 8 7;6 5 4]
xy(:,:,2) = uy; // [1 2 3;4 5 6]

aaa=xy(1,1,:); // [10 1]
bbb=xy(1,2,:); // [8 2]

dot(aaa,bbb)
```

Result will be:

```
82
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, ux and uy are matrixes of scalar values. I want to make them into vectors and put them into a matrix... or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: Hi, no sorry I'm still stuck on this. I think I've mis-communicated what I'm looking for and it's rather confused the issue. I'm not after the ability to call ux and uy in their entirety, but rather to get the scalar values from each element, combine those into a vector, and then save that vector as an element in an array.

Comment: Ok - I have to explicitly assign each vector as a variable every time I use it? That was what I wanted to avoid, because i'm doing this within a loop and each one is going to get called up several times, Maybe it doesn't matter, or maybe I just need to rethink how to do this altogether...

Comment: If ux and uy constant matrix, you dont need to assign each vector as a variable. You can call directly call dot(xy(1,1,:),xy(1,2,:))

Comment: Yes, this works - thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want it to be a cell vector, where each element is a `[1 x 2]` vector, use `mat2cell`:

```
ux = rand(15,1);
uy = rand(15,1);
U = [ux, uy];
K = mat2cell(U,ones(size(U,1),1),2);
```

But as others have pointed out, `U = [ux, uy]` is sufficient, as you can just call `U(1,:)` to get the exact same result without having to worry about cells.

If you are wanting to alculate the `dot` product on the two vectors, `arrayfun(@dot,ux,uy)` does that job element-wise.

Comment: aha - `arrayfun` might just be the thing. I'm not looking for the dot of ux and uy, though - I'm looking for the dot product of vectors made from corresponding elements of ux and uy - like `[ux(m,n), uy(m,n)].[ux(p,q), uy(p,q)]`

Comment: If you can give me examples of what your vectors contain I can maybe give a clearer answer. You can edit your original post with some examples from `ux` and `uy`.

Comment: Trying this out with a 600x300 test image, ux and uy are therefore 600x300 arrays of scalar values. doing`U = [ux, uy];` gives me a 300x1200 array, and `U(1,:);` gives me a 1x1200 array of scalar values. What am I missing here?

Comment: Up until this point I was under the impression that `ux` and `uy` are arrays. Since `[ux, uy]` is a columnwise concatenation this is fine, assuming `ux` and `uy` are columnvectors. If they are matrices, of course you have to concatenate them in the third dimension. This can be done using `U=cat(3,ux,uy)`, and then you access them using `U(i,j,1)` and `U(i,j,2)` respectively.